# AWS Glue View to restrict access to S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue-data-catalog

From reading the AWS manuals,

- it is not clear to me whether one can enforce access to S3 data for an IAM user via a AWS View only.

I am going to try it next week, but some up-front research is what I am doing first so as to save time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot, via AWS Glue Data Catalog. Need Athena or Redshift Spectrum for such an approach.